# Keep scroll bar down when text is added to pre tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure if this can be achieved with jQuery but I am developing a web terminal (like a web putty) that using a `form` will be able to send to and get messages (displaying them in the browser) from a ssh server. Then when I get ouput from a command execution (sent from ssh server to nodeJS server and then to my browser) the text is added to a text box that is set up using with a `pre` tag.

```
<body style="margin:100">
  <div id="terminal-1" class="tab-pane active">
    <pre id="output" style="height:300px; overflow: auto;"></pre>
     ^--- This one 
    <div class="row-fluid"> 
      <div class="span6">
        <form id="myForm" class="form-inline" onsubmit="return false;">
          <input type="text" class="input-large" style="width:70%" name="command" placeholder="Enter Command" autocomplete="off">
          <button id="execute" class="btn">Go!</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <! some code continues...-->
```

Then all the command output is inserted in the pre tag which makes the box be overloaded (don't know if that's the correct term) and start putting the text down, creating a bar at the right side, see the picture (marked in red):

[image]

So the final question is, which jQuery code should I add to have that bar automatically scrolled down when text is added?

Thanks

Comment: Contents should be inside pre tag not outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scroll your `<pre>` using jQuery like,

```
jQuery( function(){
   var pre = jQuery("#output");
    pre.scrollTop( pre.prop("scrollHeight") );
});
```

here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mPET6/16/)

Comment: I'll check and let you know!

Comment: Could I add some information to your comment? It has worked but, to fit the solution for my specific problem each line of code should go in different function of the jquery code

Comment: You can make a separate function like, `function scrollPre(){ var pre = jQuery("#output"); pre.scrollTop( pre.prop("scrollHeight") ); }` and call when you are appending text to `<pre/>`. :)

Comment: that's it, the .prop must be called when you add text, just that Good!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your output in a couple of divs the outer one have a fixed height and overflow-x:scroll the second one will hold your response. When you get your data back you append the data to the inner one then you get the height and then you can use scrollTop on the outer one with the height of the inner one.

This is an example

html

```
<div style="height: 100px; overflow-x:scroll;" id="console">
  <div id="console-content">
  </div>
</div>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="text">  
</form>
```

javascript

```
$(function(){
  var $form = $('#form'),
    $console = $('#console');
    $content = $('#console-content'),
    $text = $('#text');
  $('form').submit(function(event){
    var height;
    $content.append('<pre>' + $text.val() + '</pre>');
    height = $content.height();
    $console.scrollTop(height);
    $text.val('');
    event.preventDefault();
  })  
});
```

you can see the live example here

http://plnkr.co/edit/A1Okwk1r6zZW4XXdehWq?p=preview